# Java: Moving around a two dimentional array

Tags: java, arrays, events, direction

Please I have seen a lot of answers but I haven't seen the easiest solution to move around an array.

I want to continue moving to the next or previous element in the array (rows and column). Meaning if I reached the end of any rows or column, it takes me to the next or previous one, relative to the intialized size of the array.

Assuming I have a group of buttons to handle my directional events( left, right, up & down).

I have :

```
int twoD[][]= new int[3][3];
```

Output

```
0   1   2
3   4   5
6   7   8
```

I want to move right from

> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 (Continuously)

I want to move left from

> 0,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 (Continuously)

I want to move up

> 0,8,5,2,7,4,1,6,3 (Continuously)

I want to move down

> 0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8,0 (Continuously)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Typically, to iterate through a 2D array, you would use nested for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

You should have current indices for the outer and the inner array and the length of the arrays

```
int innerIndex = 0;
int outerIndex = 0;
int innerMax = 3;
int outerMax = 3;
```

If the right button is pressed you'll have to increase the inner index. If the inner index reaches innerMax you'll increase `outerIndex` and set `innerIndex` to `0`. (Best will be private methods for that)

```
private void increaseInner() {
    innerIndex++;
    if (innerIndex == innerMax) {
        innerIndex = 0;
        outerIndex++;
        if (outIndex == outerMax)
            outerIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

equivalent goes the decrase inner index: (left button pressed)

```
private void increaseInner() {
    innerIndex--;
    if (innerIndex < 0) {
        innerIndex = innerMax;
        outerIndex--;
        if (outIndex < 0)
            outerIndex = outerMax;
    }
}
```

The 2 methods for up button pressed and down button pressed are created similary to these methods.